# How to deep copy a hashmap when working with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, copy, hashmap, deep-copy

In my application I have two threads. Thread 1 is transferring data to Thread 2. After the data is transferred the data in thread 1 is cleared within thread 2. Thread 1 goes on its merry way placing more data in the HashMap as it comes in to be transferred to Thread 2 later. In the meantime, Thread 2 does what it needs to do with the data. The code I have below is the part in thread 2 where that data transfer between threads happens. The entire application works just fine, but my questions is, is there a better way to make this copy of the thread 1 data for thread 2 without using the keyword new to create a whole new object?

I figure doing this might cause more garbage collections to occur? Should I not worry about this?

```
synchronized(this){
    // Make a copy of the data map then clear it.
    cachedData = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Float>>(data);
    data.clear();
}
```

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might be able to use some sort of synchronized queue of `Map.Entry`-s instead of a map for a more continuous transfer of data.

Comment: I see, I went back through some of my old posts, deleting one's that I realized were kind of dumb, and rating answers. Thanks for sharing this information with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you are accessing this `data` `HashMap` from multiple threads then you will have to have a `synchronized` block on *every* access.  Just because you are grabbing a cached copy here does not mean that other threads get to use the `data` without synchronization.

If you want to have concurrent usage of `HashMap` *without* having to synchronize around each usage then you should be using a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

> The entire application works just fine, but my questions is, is there a better way to make this copy of the thread 1 data for thread 2 without using the keyword new to create a whole new object?

Taking into account the cautions I mentioned above, if you want to take a snapshot of a `HashMap` so you can work with the contents in a specific thread then the pattern you mention is fine and is often used.  This pattern is also used when you need to iterate through a `Collection` and modify it inside of the loop but without doing an `iterator.remove()`.

If you just need the keys or the values then make sure to take a copy of the `data.keySet()` or `data.values()` instead.

Comment: Yes, I just want a snapshot of the data to work with. I am synchronizing every access of the data in all thread as well.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
    synchronized(this){
        cachedData = data;
        data = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Float>>();
    }
```

This is similar to what you have, but involves no copying of the data.

I wouldn't worry about the `new` too much (not unless you can prove through profiling that it's a problem).

Comment: I've experienced no particular problems. I was just not sure if this was a good way to handle this.